# Generating pfx with OpenSSL api

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12

I am trying to export certificate and private key as pfx file using OpenSSL api.

To do this I am calling the [PKCS12_create](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual%3aPKCS12_create%283%29) function with -1 for nid_key and nid_cert (do not encrypt key and certificate) and 0 for iter, mac_iter and keytype (use defaults).

Result of that funciton call (plus the obvious call to i2d_PKCS12_bio) is der encoded file, which can be viewed in [asn1 decoder](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#308202F8020103308202C206092A864886F70D010701A08202B3048202AF308202AB308201BA06092A864886F70D010701A08201AB048201A7308201A33082019F060B2A864886F70D010C0A0103A082015630820152060A2A864886F70D01091601A08201420482013E3082013A3081E2A003020103020101300A06082A8648CE3D04030230133111300F06035504031308536F6D654E616D65301E170D3134303730313232303030305A170D3231303730313232303030305A30133111300F06035504031308536F6D654E616D65305A301406072A8648CE3D020106092B24030302080101070342000452932F3CC6D70327D6F74B894BE765D6B14A4A7609BFBBFC9345CD227AEDC457318AAE422111E65AEB266EB09A6D8306FC37F910F324F2BCC3B29FB35F0D8BCEA326302430220603551D11041B3019A017060504007F0007A00E0C0C3149534B3030303030303031300A06082A8648CE3D040302034700304402202AA218A626FA188D9DC48968332C83507BC5BF620F09E4522DDDCECEA6142B5202203AE2B88519FB1194869DD97137E9550A8F7345B9ABA2354D97321ABF514522763136300F06092A864886F70D01091431021E00302306092A864886F70D01091531160414A89631B5D5683B0C4CFB5512F3F5E5C8FA98AFD43081EA06092A864886F70D010701A081DC0481D93081D63081D3060B2A864886F70D010C0A0101A0818B308188020100301406072A8648CE3D020106092B2403030208010107046D306B02010104209FE48FBC313A8FB798D9C081F09FD88D6EEEEADF63C17CD2E42A8382AB9532FCA1440342000452932F3CC6D70327D6F74B894BE765D6B14A4A7609BFBBFC9345CD227AEDC457318AAE422111E65AEB266EB09A6D8306FC37F910F324F2BCC3B29FB35F0D8BCE3136300F06092A864886F70D01091431021E00302306092A864886F70D01091531160414A89631B5D5683B0C4CFB5512F3F5E5C8FA98AFD4302D3021300906052B0E03021A05000414690DF9834A338E9A0CD5EEB537F7FA76F2D892CE04080EF887B5237D8C2C).

Information from this file however can not be imported into any Windows or Firefox certificate store. Windows responds with "An internal error occurred. Either the user profile is not accessible or the private key that you are importing might require a cryptographic service provider that is not installed on your system." and Firefox responds with "The PKCS #12 operation failed for unknown reasons." The thing is that password is properly interpreted.

So what do I have to do to generate a pfx file that operating system or Firefox will accept into their stores?

**EDIT**

Some more information on what I am actually doing.

To use OpenSSL api from C# I am using ManagedOpenSsl wrapper. I added a support for EC keys to that wrapper and I can generate keys and sign certificates with those keys. Those certificates are properly displayed by the system.

I constructed two pfx files, [first one](http://lapo.it/asn1js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with the OpenSSL command line tool, [second](http://lapo.it/asn1js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with my code. The only difference in form of the files is the extra integer at the end of the first, command line generated, file. So, is there any special requirement for the content of the certificate or form of the key that I am missing?

Comment: Its hard to say what might be wrong without any code. But you might be able to look at OpenSSL's use of the function in `<openssl src>/apps/pkcs12.c`. Its the source code for the `pkcs12` utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling my hair out for two days, I found the problem.

Working for German market one of the requirements for our software is the usage of Brainpool curves. Windows operating system does not know them. Firefox does not know them. OpenSSL only knows them in beta 1.0.2. If I create NIST certificate and key and put them together in a pfx file, everything works fine.